Central units in finite group algebras
Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field and $G$ be a finite group. A unit in the group algebra $\mathbb{K}G$ is central if it lies in the center $Z(\mathbb{K}G)$.
The groups that I'm interested in are the alternating groups $A_4$, $A_5$, and the symmetric group $S_4$. Is it true that the central units in $\mathbb{F}_3A_4$, $\mathbb{F}_2A_5$ and $\mathbb{F}_3S_4$ are all multiples of the identity, i.e. $\lambda\cdot1$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{K}$? Note that these groups have trivial centers.
If we consider the corresponding group rings $\mathbb{Z}G$, then it is known that $\mathbb{Z}A_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}S_4$ only have trivial central units. $\mathbb{Z}A_5$ has non-trivial central units, but they don't survive at characteristic $2$.

If $G$ is a finite group and $\mathbb{K}$ is a field whose characteristic divides the order of $G$, then $\mathbb{K}G$ always has a central unit which is not a scalar multiple of $1$.
Let
$$x=\sum_{g\in G}g.$$
Then $x\in Z(\mathbb{K}G)$, and $x^2=\lvert G\rvert x=0$ in $\mathbb{K}G$. So $1+x$ is a central unit, with $(1+x)^{-1}=1-x$.

This is a job for a computer algebra system like sagemath.
I'm kind of surprised that sage's implementation of group algebras is as rough around the edges as it is, but it's still not so hard to make something work:
F2 = GF(2)
F3 = GF(3)

A4 = AlternatingGroup(4)
A5 = AlternatingGroup(5)
S4 = SymmetricGroup(4)

R1 = GroupAlgebra(A4,F3)
R2 = GroupAlgebra(A5,F2)
R3 = GroupAlgebra(S4,F3)

C1 = R1.center()
C2 = R2.center()
C3 = R3.center()

# This looks like the best way to iterate over our group algebras...
# I'm not sure why `for x in R1:` doesn't work, but... it doesn't.
# see here, for instance:
# https://ask.sagemath.org/question/37903/iterating-over-finite-structures/

V1 = F3**(C1.dimension())
V2 = F2**(C2.dimension())
V3 = F3**(C3.dimension())


# Check whether every unit in C1 is a multiple of the identity
for v in V1:
    x = C1.from_vector(v)
    # for some reason x.is_unit() is throwing an unimplemented error...
    # this'll get the job done, though.
    try: 
        x_inv = x.inverse()
        # a cheap way to see if x isn't a scalar multiple of 1
        if len(x.coefficients()) > 1:
            # convert back to R1 for nice printing
            x = R1(x)
            print(x)
            print(x.inverse())
            print("")
            break
    except:
        # x wasn't invertible
        pass

print("----------------------")

# Check whether every unit in C2 is a multiple of the identity
for v in V2:
    x = C2.from_vector(v)
    # for some reason x.is_unit() is throwing an unimplemented error...
    # this'll get the job done, though.
    try: 
        x_inv = x.inverse()
        # a cheap way to see if x isn't a scalar multiple of 1
        if len(x.coefficients()) > 1:
            # convert back to R1 for nice printing
            x = R2(x)
            print(x)
            print(x.inverse())
            print("")
            break
    except:
        # x wasn't invertible
        pass

print("----------------------")

# Check whether every unit in C3 is a multiple of the identity
for v in V3:
    x = C3.from_vector(v)
    # for some reason x.is_unit() is throwing an unimplemented error...
    # this'll get the job done, though.
    try: 
        x_inv = x.inverse()
        # a cheap way to see if x isn't a scalar multiple of 1
        if len(x.coefficients()) > 1:
            # convert back to R1 for nice printing
            x = R3(x)
            print(x)
            print(x.inverse())
            print("")
            break
    except:
        # x wasn't invertible
        pass

Note that searching these algebras in their entirety is likely to be too taxing, but sage can quickly compute the centers, which have a very manageable size ($81$, $32$, and $243$ elements respectively), so looping over them is entirely feasible.
Running this code gives as output
2*() + (1,2)(3,4) + (1,3)(2,4) + (1,4)(2,3)

2*() + (1,2)(3,4) + (1,3)(2,4) + (1,4)(2,3)

----------------------
(3,4,5) + (3,5,4) + (2,3)(4,5) + (2,3,4) + (2,3,5) + (2,4,3) + (2,4,5) + 
(2,4)(3,5) + (2,5,3) + (2,5,4) + (2,5)(3,4) + (1,2)(4,5) + (1,2)(3,4) + (
1,2)(3,5) + (1,2,3) + (1,2,4) + (1,2,5) + (1,3,2) + (1,3)(4,5) + (1,3,4) 
+ (1,3,5) + (1,3)(2,4) + (1,3)(2,5) + (1,4,2) + (1,4,3) + (1,4,5) + (1,4)
(3,5) + (1,4)(2,3) + (1,4)(2,5) + (1,5,2) + (1,5,3) + (1,5,4) + (1,5)(3,4
) + (1,5)(2,3) + (1,5)(2,4)

(3,4,5) + (3,5,4) + (2,3)(4,5) + (2,3,4) + (2,3,5) + (2,4,3) + (2,4,5) + 
(2,4)(3,5) + (2,5,3) + (2,5,4) + (2,5)(3,4) + (1,2)(4,5) + (1,2)(3,4) + (
1,2)(3,5) + (1,2,3) + (1,2,4) + (1,2,5) + (1,3,2) + (1,3)(4,5) + (1,3,4) 
+ (1,3,5) + (1,3)(2,4) + (1,3)(2,5) + (1,4,2) + (1,4,3) + (1,4,5) + (1,4)
(3,5) + (1,4)(2,3) + (1,4)(2,5) + (1,5,2) + (1,5,3) + (1,5,4) + (1,5)(3,4
) + (1,5)(2,3) + (1,5)(2,4)

----------------------
2*() + (1,2)(3,4) + (1,3)(2,4) + (1,4)(2,3)

2*() + (1,2)(3,4) + (1,3)(2,4) + (1,4)(2,3)

so we learn that all three algebras admit a central element that is not a scalar multiple of the identity which is a unit (indeed, which squares to $1$).
(Thanks to Jeremy Rickard both for an answer that thinks instead of hacks, and for catching the typo in my hacking)

I hope this helps ^_^

Should "x = R1.from_vector(v)" be "x = C1.from_vector(v)", and similarly for R2 and R3? When I make that change to your code, it finds the same central units of R1 and R3 that you did, but also finds one for R2.

@JeremyRickard, ah, good catch! Thanks

The only reason I think instead of hacking is that I'm not good enough at hacking. At least, I think that's the reason.
